# How to create mobile sitemap correctly using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, sitemap

I'm trying to create mobile sitemap using JAXB. According to [google documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34648?hl=en&ref_topic=2370586), it should have following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0">
    <url>
        <loc>http://mobile.example.com/article100.html</loc>
        <mobile:mobile/>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

To solve this problem I created following beans:

URL.java :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(propOrder = {"loc"})
public class URL {

    private String loc;

    @XmlElement
    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }
}
```

URLSet.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="urlset")
public class URLSet{

    private List<URL> urlset;

    @XmlAttribute(name="xmlns")
    private String xmlns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";

    public URLSet() {
        urlset = new ArrayList<URL>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name="url")
    public List<URL> getUrlset() {
        return urlset;
    }

    public void setUrlset(List<URL> urlset) {
        this.urlset = urlset;
    }

}
```

marshalling:

```
List<URL> list = new ArrayList<URL>();
URLSet urlSet = new URLSet();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    URL url = new URL();
    url.setLoc("www.test" + i + ".com");
    list.add(url);
}
urlSet.setUrlset(list);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(URLSet.class);
Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
//m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
//m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
//m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(urlSet,sw);
log.info("\n" + sw.toString() + "\n");
```

The questions are: how can I add static `<mobile:mobile/>` child to every  node? how should I name mobile sitemap file in case I store this together with desktop "sitemap.xml" ? Thanks in advance.